# How to efficiently calculate distances of n points in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, distance, nearest-neighbor

I am new to Python and am currently writing a python postprocessing tool for my simulation of active spheres.

The main function is:

```
counter = 0
for data in itertools.islice(data_iter, begin_timestep, last_timestep-1): #<-- loop over timesteps
    pos = data[:,3:5]
    dx = pos[:,None,:] - pos[None,:,:] #<-- calculation of the distances in 2D
    dx -= extent[None,None,:] * np.floor(0.5  + dx / extent[None,None,:]) #<-- correct for periodic boundaries
    pairwise_distance = np.sqrt(np.sum(dx ** 2.0, axis=-1))
    Q6_2 = calculate_nn_andreas_q2(dx[...,1], dx[...,0], pairwise_distance, 6) #<-- calculate the hexagonal order parameter for each sphere
    mean_Q6_2[counter] = np.mean(Q6_2)
    counter=counter+1
```

Which calculates a hexagonal order parameter (Q6) for all spheres where the position of the 6 nearest neighbours is essential.

As this script runs longer than 24 hours for ~3000 spheres and 20k time steps, I need to optimize this.

The main problem is the distance (dx) calculation. Here, I only evaluate 2 coordinates, as the system is Quasi-2D. 
I was thinking about optimizing the distance calculation by putting a grid over the system and only comparing spheres with each other that are in the same or neighbouring cells as I only need the 6 nearest neighbours for the Q6 calculation. Is there an efficient way of doing this in Python or an even better algorithm to find the 6 nearest neighbours?

Comment: What does `data` look like?  can you post an example?

Comment: Also, where does `extent` come from?